# Looking for guidance on my sql query that apparently includes an array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Quite new to sql, and looking for help on what i'm doing wrong.

With the code below, i'm getting the error "cannot access field value on a value with type array<struct> at [1:30]"

The "audience size value" comes from the dataset `public_campaigns` where as the engagement rate comes from the data set `public_instagram_channels`

I think the dataset that's causing the issue here is the public_campaigns.

thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

```
SELECT creator_audience_size.value, AVG(engagement_rate/1000000) AS avgER
FROM `public_instagram_channels` AS pic
JOIN `public_campaigns`AS pc
ON pic.id=pc.id 
GROUP BY creator_audience_size.value
```

Comment: HI you are going to need to provide more detail. 1) tag with database platform. Please don't post images of text, as then someone cannot copy/paste the data to try to run it.  show the table definitions (i.e. "create table ...") so we can see all the fields names and types.

Comment: Which dataset is it you're using?  I can't find this in BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the type of one of the columns using `REPEATED` mode.

In Google BigQuery you have to use `UNNEST` on these repeated columns to get their individual values in the result set.

It's unclear from what you've posted which column is the repeated type - looking at the table definition for `public_instagram_channels` and `public_campaigns` will reveal this - look for the word `REPEATED` in the `Mode` column of the table definition.

Once you've found it, include `UNNEST` in your query, as per this untested example:

```
SELECT  creator_audience_size.value, AVG(engagement_rate/1000000) AS avgER
  FROM  `public_instagram_channels` AS pic,
        UNNEST(`column_name`) AS whatever_you_want
    JOIN `public_campaigns`AS pc ON pic.id = pc.id 
  GROUP BY creator_audience_size.value
```